# I don't know how to send data through variable on this file PHP

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I don't know how to send data through variable on this code

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Telegram\Bot\Api;
$telegram = new Api('376072170:AAE2_y5EpVRCwc8Xbe-GHJLNP9yUdP2Zzto');
$chatid=$_POST['id'];
$text=$_POST['msg'];
$response = $telegram->sendMessage([
  'chat_id' => 'chatid', 
  'text' => 'some text here'
]);
$messageId = $response->getMessageId();
```

I did something like this

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Telegram\Bot\Api;
$telegram = new Api('376072170:AAE2_y5EpVRCwc8Xbe-GHJLNP9yUdP2Zzto');
$chatid=$_POST['id'];
$text=$_POST['msg'];
$response = $telegram->sendMessage([
  'chat_id' => $chatid, 
  'text' => $text
]);
$messageId = $response->getMessageId();
```

but all that I get is an error 500 on the browser what should I do to can get it to work 
I wanna send data through a form but I don't know what to do 
thanks for your help

this is my heroku log

> 2017-03-26T13:19:25.215850+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/msg.php" host=telebotyx.herokuapp.com request_id=cc595063-19ca-48a2-9f19-5832d79d4603 fwd="200.73.16.3" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1164ms status=500 bytes=169 protocol=https
>   2017-03-26T13:19:25.229754+00:00 app[web.1]: [26-Mar-2017 13:19:25 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Telegram\Bot\Exceptions\TelegramOtherException: Bad Request: message text is empty in /app/vendor/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/src/Exceptions/TelegramResponseException.php:58
>   2017-03-26T13:19:25.229763+00:00 app[web.1]: Stack trace:
>   2017-03-26T13:19:25.229821+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 /app/vendor/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/src/TelegramResponse.php(174): Telegram\Bot\Exceptions\TelegramResponseException::create(Object(Telegram\Bot\TelegramResponse))
>   2017-03-26T13:19:25.229931+00:00 app[web.1]: #1 /app/vendor/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/src/TelegramResponse.php(204): Telegram\Bot\TelegramResponse->makeException()
>   2017-03-26T13:19:25.230043+00:00 app[web.1]: #2 /app/vendor/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/src/TelegramResponse.php(65): Telegram\Bot\TelegramResponse->decodeBody()
>   2017-03-26T13:19:25.230206+00:00 app[web.1]: #3 /app/vendor/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/src/TelegramClient.php(138): Telegram\Bot\TelegramResponse->__construct(Object(Telegram\Bot\TelegramRequest), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
>   2017-03-26T13:19:25.230367+00:00 app[web.1]: #4 /app/vendor/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/src/TelegramClient.php(119): Telegram\Bot\TelegramClient->getResponse(Object(Telegram\Bot\TelegramRequest), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
>   2017-03-26T13:19:25.230513+00:00 app[web.1]: #5 /app/vendor/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/src/Api.php in /app/vendor/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/src/Exceptions/TelegramResponseException.php on line 58
>   2017-03-26T13:19:25.231648+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.179.109.26 - - [26/Mar/2017:13:19:24 +0000] "GET /msg.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.110 Safari/537.36

Comment: Please enable debugging mode and add your error message.

Comment: there is my heroku log

Comment: "Bad Request: message text is empty". Are you sure that you are passing a text for the $_POST['msg']?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something is going wrong in your form. Since the error is "... Bad Request: message text is empty..."

Check if your input field names are 'id' and 'msg'.
Also check if your form method is POST.

Comment: yes all is ok my form is in another file so the problem is inside of the code posted above

Comment: What if you try to hard code a message in $text? Do you still get an error?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using [POST](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) to transmit your form.

> method=GET path="/msg.php"

Either switch to [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.request.php) or use POST in the [HTML tag](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_form_method.asp):

```
<form action="/msg.php" method="post">
```

Comment: <form method="POST" action="msg.php">
<input name="id" id="id" type="text" plceholder="chat id" />
<input name="msg" id="msg" type="text" plceholder="Mensaje" />
<input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
thats my form